# The impact of avoiding let variable bindings

Tags: rust, allocation

Having fun with a project using `gdnative`, I wrote this:

```
#[method]
fn _save_player_position(&mut self, player_current_position: VariantArray) {
    let player_current_position: (f64, f64) = (
        player_current_position.get(0).to::<f64>().unwrap(),
        player_current_position.get(1).to::<f64>().unwrap()
    );
    self.player_data.set_player_position(player_current_position.0, player_current_position.1);
    self.received_signals += 1;
}
```

My doubt is, do you "win" some benefit by rewrite the code like this:

```
#[method]
fn _save_player_position(&mut self, player_current_position: VariantArray) {
    self.player_data.set_player_position(
        player_current_position.get(0).to::<f64>().unwrap(),
        player_current_position.get(1).to::<f64>().unwrap()
    );
    self.received_signals += 1;
}
```

As far as I know, I am avoiding:

- The creation of a new tuple struct
- Storing the data in it's unnamed fields
- Saving the data on the `let player_current_position`
- Then moving the data to some of the `self` fields

And the questions are:

- Is the above true?
- Is worth starting code like this in order to avoid allocations (even if they are in the stack)
- Is better to only optimize `heap` ones, and improve readability whenever it's possible?

Comment: Realistically, both are very likely to identical machine code, with the two `f64`s stored in registers. It's not worth giving up clarity for some possible performance, unless you've benchmarked and know that the benefits are significant.

Comment: Also, tuple structs look like `struct Custom(f64, f64); let custom = Custom(3.0, 5.2);`. What you use is just called a "tuple".

Comment: Personally I would write `let x = ...` and `let y = ...` since it is clearer to write `x, y` than `some_tuple.0, some_tuple.1`. In any case, there is likely no difference (or no meaningful difference) in the compiled output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the compiler output for both cases (slightly rewritten for clarity) here:

https://godbolt.org/z/Gc4nr6afb

```
struct Foo {
    pos : (f64, f64),
}
impl Foo {
    fn bar(&mut self, current : (f64, f64)) {
        let player_current_position: (f64, f64) = (
            current.0,
            current.1,
        );
        self.pos = (player_current_position.0, player_current_position.1);
    }

    fn bar2(&mut self, current : (f64, f64)) {
        self.pos = (current.0, current.1);
    }
}


pub fn main() { 
    let mut foo = Foo {pos: (1.0, 1.0)};
    foo.bar((2.0,2.0));
    foo.bar2((2.0,2.0));
}
```

this is with local variables:

```
Foo::bar:
        sub     rsp, 16
        movsd   qword ptr [rsp], xmm0
        movsd   qword ptr [rsp + 8], xmm1
        movsd   xmm1, qword ptr [rsp]
        movsd   xmm0, qword ptr [rsp + 8]
        movsd   qword ptr [rdi], xmm1
        movsd   qword ptr [rdi + 8], xmm0
        add     rsp, 16
        ret
```

and this is without

```
Foo::bar2:
        movsd   qword ptr [rdi], xmm0
        movsd   qword ptr [rdi + 8], xmm1
        ret
```

Note that as per @Jmb comment, once compiler optimisation is enabled, the output will be identical: https://godbolt.org/z/xKPfMP6Yr

Comment: That's exactly the kind of answer that I was looking for. People on comments was ensuring that there's no meaningful difference between the two snippets, and I am not proficent with assembly. Can you explain the basic diffs between the both versions?

Comment: Note that if you [enable optimization](https://godbolt.org/z/xKPfMP6Yr), the compiler generates the same code for both (actually it only generates a single function with both names).

Comment: Comparing unoptimized assembly is meaningless.

Comment: @AlexVergara when you declare local variables in a function, they live on the stack. The rsp register points to the top of the stack, so by sub rsp and add rsp at the beginning and end of the bar version, you are allocating stack space for them. The next two lines copy the input params from the registers xmm0 and xmm1 to this allocated space, and the following two lines move the values from the stack to the registers, so that they can use to update the struct members in the next two lines. The second version, bar2, only has these two lines, moving from the input registers to the struct fields.

Comment: @Jmb added an edit to the answer, ta.